# CSS: Div with height:100% is pushed down by his brothers div

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have in one div three other children divs placed one above the other. The third one is a *JqueryMobile listview* that needs `overflow-y: scroll` to make only the *listview* scrollable without need to scroll all the page.
The problem is that if I set the `height` of the *listview* to `100%`, this will set its height to the same of the parent without calculating that there are two other divs that occupy space and so it will go out the limit of the page so that some rows will not be displayed.

How can I tell the *listview* to fill the parent without overflowing the page ?

==Edit==

This is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/q4Mwz/3/
As you can see the height of the div listview is setted to 100% and you cannot see the last li "Last Element" bacause they have overflowed the page

Comment: uff.. its very difficult to understand in theoretical manner. Why can't you create a fiddle?

Comment: Please post your code, or at least a link to a fiddle.

Comment: Wait a moment... I'm working on it

Comment: This is normal behavior, since your body height is limited to 480px. You could make your body higher or your content smaller.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a scrollable element fill 100% of the remaining height of a parent element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906688/how-to-make-a-scrollable-element-fill-100-of-the-remaining-height-of-a-parent-e)

Comment: @stekhn i can't make my body bigger or my content smaller because i'm working in a cordova mobile app and so it needs to be all in percentage

Comment: you can try making all the three elements' height in percentage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved with a simple jQuery script that take the height of the page and subtract the heights of the others elements:

```
    var h = $('#page').outerHeight(true) - $('#combo').outerHeight(true) - $('#header').outerHeight(true) -15;
    $('#listview_height').height(h);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want two `div`s to sit about `div.listview` and you want them to collectively fill the height of the parent `div.noscroll`, then naturally giving `div.listview` a height of 100% is going to overflow the parent.

If what you want is to have `div.listview` fill the *rest* of the parent's height, one solution would be to give the first two `divs` a height of 10% and then give `div.listview` a height of 80%.